# HTML "Range" Input Problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm trying to write a slider program that will cover an entire square canvas with a blue square when range is set to maximum. There are two problems I'm having though:

1. When moving my slider, it produces a rectangle instead of a square.
2. The maximum value of my slider's square only covers less than half of the canvas.

I'm doing my project on Codepen, and my code for the slider is below. Here's a link to my pen if you need the full details: https://codepen.io/drummerlover33/pen/EXdobV.

```
function doSquare() {
  var slider = document.getElementById("colorSlider");
  var sliderValue = slider.value;
  var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  canvasContext.fillStyle = "blue";
  canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,sliderValue,sliderValue);
}
```

Hope you can help a newbie out!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas's [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) and [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/height) attributes are not only the size of the canvas, but also set its resolution. If you don't set `width` and `height` via the attributes (or via script), the canvas's default resolution is **300px X 150px**.

Setting the dimensions via CSS only sets the outer size of the canvas element (the style). You have to set the `width` and the `height` attributes explicitly on the canvas element.

```js
// Remnant function from previous case
function doRed() {
  var canvasElements = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  canvasElements.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
// END of remnant function

var slider = document.getElementById("colorSlider");
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

function doSquare() {
  var sliderValue = slider.value;
  canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvasContext.fillStyle = "blue";
  canvasContext.fillRect(
    0,
    0,
    sliderValue,
    sliderValue
  );
}

function doColor() {
  var canvasElements = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  var pickedColor = document.getElementById("colorInput").value;
  canvasElements.style.backgroundColor = pickedColor;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inputs and Events</h1>
<canvas id="mainCanvas" height="100px" width="100px"></canvas>

<p>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="colorSlider" oninput="doSquare()">

  <input type="color" value="#ffffff" id="colorInput" onchange="doColor()">
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Still having a hard time understanding how setting height and width is different in HTML and CSS. Would you know if there's a resource I can read up on to help me understand this?

Comment: The canvas has two 2 "sizes" - the outer size - the size of the html element itself, and the inner size - the resolution in pixels of the drawing area. Attributes define both, while the style (css) define only the outer.